# Import list to Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a list (with list inside) in R and need import to C using Rcpp.

```
# R
MainList <- list()
MainList$myint <- 2
MainList$mylist <- list(matrix(1,2,2), matrix(2,2,2))
MainList
```

My goal is import the list in R (MainList$mylist in example) and copy to one 3D array in C.

I tried this:

```
// Rcpp

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List MyFunction (List MainList){  
    int N =  as<int>(MainList["myint"]);
    List mylistRcpp = as<List>(MainList["mylist"]); // It this work? Apparently no

    double*** mylistC; // already with allocate memory

    for (int h=0; h<N; h++){
        NumericMatrix temp = mylistRcpp[h];
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
            for (int n=0; n<N; n++){
                mylistC[h][i][n] = temp(i, n);
            }
        }
    }


    return List::create(Named("1") = N,
                        Named("2") = N);
    }
```

I can import the list this way? There are some easy way to copy without copy one by one? I need the 3D array for another function. I not sure about how import the list from R to Rcpp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can insert an Rcpp::List inside an Rcpp::List and recurse as deep as you want. No need for double** and other gymnastics.

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List ListExample() {

  std::string abc   = "def";
  double tol        = 0.001;

  Rcpp::List l = Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("method", abc),
                                    Rcpp::Named("tolerance", tol));
  Rcpp::List ll = Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("method", abc),
                                     Rcpp::Named("tolerance", tol),
                                     Rcpp::Named("list", l));
  return ll;
}

/*** R
ListExample()
*/
```

#### Demo

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/soQ.cpp")

R> ListExample()
$method
[1] "def"

$tolerance
[1] 0.001

$list
$list$method
[1] "def"

$list$tolerance
[1] 0.001


R>
```

As you can see we have a list inside a list.

Comment: The problem is that I need the 3D array for another function. I not sure about how import the list from R to Rcpp. Thanks, Vanderlei

Comment: Similar questions have been answered before, both for Rcpp arrays (vectors with `dim` of more than two) and `arma::cube`.